# NPM authentication with private feeds fails for dotnet publish on ADO pipeline

Tags: npm, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Setup**
I have created a new project using `dotnet new react`.
My code is on Azure DevOps GIT.
I am using a npm module published on a private registry in the same ADO organization.

**Issue**
In my build pipeline, my `dotnet publish` task fail with the following error

```
npm ERR! code E401
  npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Basic realm="https://xxxxxxxxxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
  
  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2020-10-23T16_16_30_880Z-debug.log
D:\a\1\s\Portal.csproj(48,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1.
```

**Things I have tried**

1. Added an [npm authentciate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops) task before the dotnet publish task. That task passes but I get the 401 error in the publish task.

Answer (score 0):

> NPM authentication with private feeds fails for dotnet publish on ADO pipeline

According to the [npm Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops) (for task runners):

> Use this task to provide npm credentials to an .npmrc file in your
> repository for the scope of the build. **This enables npm, as well as
> npm task runners like gulp and Grunt, to authenticate with private
> registries**.

SO, it not work with `dotnet publish` task. To resolve this issue, you could try to use npm task, like `npm install` to restore the packages and `npm build` to build the project, then use the [Azure App Service deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) to publish the react project.

You could check [this blog](http://How%20to%20continuously%20deploy%20a%20ReactJS%20website%20to%20Azure%20using%20VSTS) for some more details.

Comment: The blog you suggested works for pure reactjs sites. however, I also have dotnet controllers in the same project, If i just use npm tasks, how should i deploy the controllers?

Comment: @ShaswatRungta, You could try to add a dotnet restore task to restore the package for the dotnet controllers projects Not all projects, then use the `dotnet publish --no-restore`.